# SQL query using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Category Table have:

- category code
- category name

Items table have:

- category code
- Item Code
- Item Name

Old Table have :

- Category Code
- Old code
- Old Detail
```

Now I want To Show The table In the Format of

`Category Code  | Category Name | Item Code | Item Name | Old Code | Old Detail`s

all the three table have same category code

I used This query :-

```
 SELECT dbo.N_items.CategoryCode, dbo.N_items.ItemCode AS [New Code], dbo.N_items.ItemDetail AS [New Detail], dbo.OldMasterTable.OldItemCode AS [Old Code],   dbo.OldMasterTable.OldItemDetails AS [Old Detail]
FROM   dbo.OldMasterTable INNER JOIN  dbo.N_items 
ON dbo.N_items.CategoryCode = dbo.OldMasterTable.CategoryCode
```

But the Details of Item table is repeating

Comment: use group by category_code

Comment: There is a column `ItemDetail` in your query, but not in the design you have shown.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#, PHP or ASP.Net?!

Comment: there should be only sql-server or mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY`, also use alias names for easiness:

```
SELECT C.CategoryCode, 
       I.ItemCode AS [New Code], 
       I.ItemDetail AS [New Detail], 
       O.OldItemCode AS [Old Code], 
       O.OldItemDetails AS [Old Detail]
FROM Category C JOIN
     Items I ON C.CategoryCode=I.CategoryCode JOIN
     OldMasterTable O ON C.CategoryCode=O.CategoryCode
GROUP BY C.CategoryCode, I.ItemCode AS [New Code], 
         I.ItemDetail AS [New Detail], O.OldItemCode AS [Old Code], 
         O.OldItemDetails AS [Old Detail]
```

Comment: No, It was not helpful, It was still repeating the details of Item Table,

Comment: I Tried many ways but the details of item table is still repeating

Comment: @Shubhankar: How does it result duplicates even after grouping by. Please show the result it produces and the result you required.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution - It will not repeat Item table details. Just keep Item Table first before Joining. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
SELECT c.CategoryCode, c.CategoryName, i.ItemCode, i.ItemName, o.OldItemCode, o.OldItemDetails
FROM  Items i 
LEFT JOIN CategoryTable c on i.CategoryCode = c.CategoryCode
LEFT JOIN OldMasterTable o ON i.CategoryCode = o.CategoryCode
```

Comment: No, It was not helpful, It was still repeating the details of Item Table,